# How to enumerate a cell of strings with unique numbers?

Tags: string, matlab, unique, enumeration

Let's say I have an `N x 1` cell (let's set N = 5) where each element is a string that can be repeated. So an example would be this:

```
x = {'x', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'd'}
```

I want to determine the unique strings and obtain an `N x 1` identifier vector, which, for this case, is:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```

No alphabetical ordering is required, I just want each integer in `y` correspond to a unique string in `x`. Is there an easy way to do this in MATLAB?

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Pretty much the same as the duplicate. You can ignore the plotting part though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: use the third output of [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'stable'` input flag:

```
[~, ~, result] = unique(x, 'stable');
```

Comment: Thanks! I will accept asap.

Comment: Dear Luis, I have another question. How can I know which id corresponds to which entry in x? so if I want to access the original string value from the numeric id, what should I do?

Comment: @HalilPazarlama If I understand correctly, just use `result` as an index into `x`.. So for example `x{result(2)}` will give the original second string. But you could as well just use `x{2}`